# Knockout text with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I'm working on an intro to a website and I want to make the text cut through a mask to the background behind it. An example of what I'd like is [here](https://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-intro-section/video.html) but they use SVG to accomplish the effect. I'm almost completely brand new to SVG and would like to know if there is an alternative way to achieve this with CSS. If not, I could definitely use any recommendations for creating SVG text in the simplest way possible for a newbie.

[My site with complete html/css/jQuery code can be seen in this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/dns32peu/)

The basic intro mask and text layout in the html is

```
  <div id="intro">
    <div id="mask"></div>
    <div id="introText">
      <p>time to get away...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The corresponding CSS is

```
#mask {
 opacity:0.8;
 background-color: rgba(0, 131, 255, 0.9);
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 z-index:1000;
}

#introText {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 33%;
  font-size: 6em;
}
```

Comment: Wow, site intros are coming back? Did we not learn anything from the piles of empirical data from the previous decade? You should put analytics on the before and after and watch your bounce rate jump, and then start practicing the speech about how the only people who think site intros are cool are the site owners ;)

Comment: Wow, what a helpful comment. It's for a school project that requires it. Thanks so much

Comment: You can use CSS3 to vary opacity: see https://jsfiddle.net/arifbdev/vaLatLvx/

Answer (score -2):

Start with a **div** width of zero, and slowly expand it to full size using jQuery animation.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer how to knock out text, please update or delete it.